# PostCSS css-next - global variables without having to use @import

Tags: webpack, postcss, cssnext, postcss-import

I have a file `variables.css` with CSS variables inside a `:root{}`

Right now each time I need to use it in another `.css` file I use:

> `@import './path/to/variables.css'`.

I want to know if **there is a way to have `variables.css` available globally without having to import it every single time I need it.**

I tried to use the option `customProperties` on `cssnext` plugin, but it gives an error compiling css to a js object...
I'm using `React` with `webpack 1` and as postcss plugins I have `import`, `mixins`, `cssnext` and `nested`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, no, but you can make your life easier. In your config for import, set the path, such as:

`cssImport({ path: './src' })`

And assuming your `variables.css` is in `src/variables.css`, you can simply do:

`@import 'variables';`

instead of dot walking back up the tree to find the right spot.

Comment: Nah, that doesn't help because i have `@import` from other paths than ./src. Thanks anyway

Comment: Right, no worries. Yeah I use absolute across the board which probably makes things easier, but doesn't apply in your case

Answer (score 0):

You import the variable.css to main.css(your global css file)

```
//main.css
@import "./variable.css";
```

Then in _app.js import the main.css:

```
// Your path to main.css
import "../assets/main.css"
```